# Azure pronunciation/fluency assessment for non-native english speaker

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-speech

I am using azure speech's fluency assessment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-pronunciation-assessment?pivots=programming-language-python

My questions is:  **the scoring returned keeping a native english speaker as reference. Is there a way to create score keeping a non-native english speaker in mind?**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that just be lower scores across the board?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not always there are those that are non-native but speak very good english. folks like them should not penalised

Comment: Then they would get a good score? I'm probably missing the point here.

Comment: ideally yes but thats not what is happening!

Comment: Currently Pronunciation assessment is only available for en-us & en-uk locales but I guess you can change the language locale to the variant of English say en-in (when it becomes available) instead of using the default en-us so that region specific pronunciations are considered - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#neural-voices

Comment: This seems crazy. There are probably niches (acting, espionage) where acquiring an authentic non-native accent is important, but expecting a general-purpose tool to support this is just unrealistic and slightly weird.